# Tangent space base and index notation

Tags: differential-geometry, index-notation

Let $\{e_\mu\}$ be a base for vectors and $\{\omega^\mu\}$ for dual vectors that we write
$e_\mu=e_\mu^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ and $\omega^\mu=\omega_\mu^id x^i$ with $e_\mu^i\omega^\nu_i=\delta^\nu_\mu$ (and $i$, $j$ coordinate components).
Further we have the commutator rule $[e_\mu,e_\nu]=\gamma_{\mu\nu}^\rho e_\rho$ with $\gamma_{\mu\nu}^\rho$ the commutator components.

My questions is

> What are these $\gamma_{\mu\nu}^\rho$?

I want to prove the identity $$e_\mu^ie_\nu^j\frac{\partial\omega^\sigma_j}{\partial x^i}-e_\nu^ie_\mu^j\frac{\partial\omega^\sigma_j}{\partial x^i}=-\gamma_{\mu\nu}^\sigma,$$
but I don't know where to start if I don't know what these $\gamma$ are.

Comment: They're uniquely defined by the given rule, where the commutator is the Lie bracket. More explicitly we can write $\gamma^\rho_{\mu \nu} = \omega^\rho_i [e_\mu,e_\nu]^i.$

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis How would I use this to prove the identity then?

Comment: The usual expression for the Lie bracket will let you write $\gamma$ in terms of partial derivatives of $e$. Differentiating the relation $e\omega = \delta$ should let you express this terms of derivatives of $\omega$ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting on the left,
$$ e_{\mu}^i e_{\nu}^j \frac{\partial \omega^{\sigma}_j}{\partial x^i} - e_{\nu}^i e_{\mu}^j \frac{\partial \omega^{\sigma}_j}{\partial x^i} = e_{\mu}^i  \frac{\partial }{\partial x^i} (e_{\nu}^j\omega^{\sigma}_j) - \omega^{\sigma}_j e_{\mu}^i  \frac{\partial e_{\nu}^j }{\partial x^i} - e_{\nu}^i  \frac{\partial }{\partial x^i} (e_{\mu}^j\omega^{\sigma}_j) + \omega^{\sigma}_j e_{\nu}^i  \frac{\partial e_{\mu}^j}{\partial x^i} \\
= 0 - \omega^{\sigma}_j \left( e_{\mu}^i  \frac{\partial e_{\nu}^j }{\partial x^i} - e_{\nu}^i  \frac{\partial e_{\mu}^j}{\partial x^i} \right), $$
using that $e_{\nu}^j \omega^{\sigma}_j = \delta^{\sigma}_{\nu}$ is constant, and the bracket is the coordinate expression of the Lie bracket, $[e_{\mu},e_{\nu}]^j$.